# Can't view input part of snippet editor

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

For some reason, when I try to open the stack snippets editor, I only see the sidebar, and I don't see the input fields on the right side.

Here's a screenshot of the problem (along with the console output, which doesn't show any errors):

[image: Screenshot]

I'm running **Google Chrome 54.0.2840.16 beta** on **Linux Mint 18**.

Comment: You're using a dev release, which is not supported. Works fine in chrome 53 (Stable)

Comment: I can still reproduce this in Chorme 54 beta, and therefore I suspect this will still be a problem once Chrome stable reaches 54.

Comment: OP did write what he is facing... What the the reason to downvote ?

Comment: Installing stable release `53.0.2785.113 m (64-bit)` solved my problem!

Comment: Version 54.0.2840.27 beta (64-bit) same problem persists.

Comment: Same issue at chromium 54.0.2840.27 (Developer Build) (32-bit)